# Folders in Controllers directory in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm kind of new to ASP.Net MVC 4. I'm working on an app that will have a lot of routes. With that in mind, I'm running into naming conflicts in my Controller. Because of this, I've decided that I want to split up my Controller into multiple controllers. In an attempt to keep things clean, I feel I have a need to put Controller classes in subdirectories within the Controllers directory. My questions are:

1. Is this even an option? I can't seem to find any examples with
   this approach
2. How do I register the Controllers that are in the
   subdirectories such that when I add routes in the RouteConfig.cs
   file, they leverage the controller that is in a subdirectory?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to consider using areas instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 8):

Is this an option? Definitely. You can place the controllers wherever you want. MVC would automatically scan the assembly for controllers and it doesn't matter if they are placed only under `Controllers`.

If things get more complex, and you want better organization, you can leverage the concept of `Areas` in ASP.NET MVC - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx